# Why wont this ajax script call the backend php using ajaxRequest.open?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

```
<html><head><title>Loses</title></head><body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction() {
    var ajaxRequest;
    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (e){
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Receive data from the server to update div
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
            ajaxDisplay.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

    // Get the value from user.
    if (!target) target = document.getElementById("name");
    var queryString = "?name=" + escape(target.value);

    var url = "db.php" + queryString;

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
</script>

<form name="myForm">
    Victim: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/> <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" onclick="getLoses()" value="Show Loses"/>
</form>

<div id="ajaxDiv">Results:</div>
<br>

</body></html>
```

Why doesn't this do anything?

I've tried it under apache and lightpd. I'm getting no complaints or errors, but it's just not doing anything.

If I call the backend manually, db.php?name=Player1 it works. So it can't be anything in db.php. Something is wrong with the code above and I just don't know what's missing. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. You call a function getLoses() on button-click, but there is  no such function(the name is ajaxFunction)
2. `if (!target) target = document.getElementById("name");`

   there is no variable target, so  the check for `!target` will result in a script-error.
   Remove the `if(!target)` from that line or change the condition to :

   ```
   if (typeof target=='undefined' || !target)
   ```

Comment: Oops, I was trying to fix it using other examples I saw, and I left the function name ajaxFunction, but even after changing it back to getLoses (or changing the onclick call it ajaxFunction) and removing the if(!target), it still doesn't work.

Comment: In the server log, I see: "GET /db.php?name=Player1 HTTP/1.1" 200 525 "http://127.0.0.1/?name=Player1"

Although the GET has db.php?, the url after it doesn't have the db.php. Is that part of the problem?

Comment: No, the 2nd url is the referer. Are you sure that db.php is located in the DOCUMENT_ROOT?